# How to sort last group based on first value

Tags: java

Input

```
    1-Y-YYY-100.55.23.20
    1-Y-YYY-100.55.23.21
    1-Y-YYY-100.55.24.A
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.22.D
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.23.22
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.23.67
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.23.D
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.23.E
    0-Y-YYY-100.55.24.D
    1-Y-YYY-101.55.23.D
    0-Y-YYY-101.55.23.E
    1-Y-YYY-100.200.23.B
    1-Y-YYY-100.200.29.D
    0-Y-YYY-100.200.29.A
    1-Y-YYY-100.51.23.D
    1-Y-YYY-100.51.24.D
    1-Y-YYY-100.56.23.D
    1-Y-YYY-101.51.23.F
    1-Y-YYY-101.151.235.D
    1-Y-YYY-100.151.242.D
```

Expected Output:

```
    1-A-ABC-100.55.24.A
    1-A-ABC-100.55.23.F
    1-A-ABC-100.55.23.21
    1-A-ABC-100.55.23.20
    1-A-ABC-100.55.21.E
    0-A-ABC-100.55.22.D
    0-A-ABC-100.55.23.D
    0-A-ABC-100.55.23.E
    0-A-ABC-100.55.23.22
    0-A-ABC-100.55.24.D
    1-A-ABC-101.55.23.D
    0-A-ABC-101.55.23.E
    1-A-ABC-100.200.29.D
    1-A-ABC-100.200.23.B
    0-A-ABC-100.200.29.A
    1-A-ABC-100.51.24.D
    1-A-ABC-100.51.23.F
    1-A-ABC-100.56.23.D
    1-A-ABC-101.51.23.D
    1-A-ABC-101.151.235.D
    1-A-ABC-100.151.242.D
```

When 1 group of line comes (till first dot is one group), we need to sort the last 2 value by descending

When 0 group of line comes (till first dot is one group), we need to sort the last 2 value by ascending

Example

> 0-Y-YYY-100 is a different group then 0-Y-YYY-101

How to achieve this?

I write a own comparator and tried with

```
group1.thenComparing(group2.reversed()).thenComparing(group3);
```

Looks it cannot be done with the comparator....

```
Group1: 100.51 or 101.51 etc., Group2 etc., 
Comparator group1 = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> (Integer) map.get(s.group)); 
Comparator group2= Comparator.comparing(s -> s.emptyOrOne); 
Comparator group3= Comparator.comparing(s -> s.last); 
group1 .thenComparing(group2.reversed()).thenComparing(group3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome here. Have you tried a solution and do you face a particular problem you cannot solve? Would you also share your attempt? It would help us to give you a more focused solution.

Comment: @dolphin trendz how input information is stored?

Comment: I write a own comparator and tried with group1.thenComparing(group2.reversed()).thenComparing(group3); Looks it cannot be done with the comparator....So i posted with the details

Comment: Group1: 100.51 or 101.51 etc., Group2 etc.,     Comparator group1 = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> (Integer) map.get(s.group));
        Comparator group2= Comparator.comparing(s -> s.emptyOrOne);
        Comparator group3= Comparator.comparing(s -> s.last);
        return group1 .thenComparing(group2.reversed()).thenComparing(group3);

Comment: Please, update your question and include your attempt. I'll take a look at it

Comment: I have updated the question Nikolas..Thanks in advance